# PDO оператор LIKE

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Жлброго времени суток, есть метод который должен вести поиск из БД(PDO), Но 
выводит все время результат **array(0) { }**

```
  public function search(){
    $params = [
                'title' => $_GET['search'],         
            ];  
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login LIKE %:title%",$params);
            $result_search = array();
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $result_search[] = $row;
        }
        return $result_search;
        }


    ////// вывод
        $res_search =   $this->model->search();
             var_dump($res_search);
```

Comment: %:title% надо заключить в ещё одни кавычки т.к. это строка

Comment: Maximmka, '%':login'%' так заключил и так '%:login%', результат тот же

Comment: query у pdo принимает только один пользовательский параметр - сам запрос. напиши в query запрос в чистом виде, убери из него ,$params

Comment: Maximmka, если LIKE заменить на '=' и ввести полную строку то работает

Comment: не может оно работать. посмотрите синтаксис SQL, если написать две строки рядом, то они не будут объединены никогда. используйте принятый в вашем диалекте SQL синтаксис конкатенации строк. Postgresql: `'%'||:title||'%'`, MySQL: `concat('%',:title,'%')`, или соберите строку заранее на PHP и передавайте в запрос готовую

Comment: Mike, таким способом заработало)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте принятый в вашем диалекте SQL синтаксис конкатенации строк.

Postgresql:

```
'%'||:title||'%',
```

MySQL:

```
concat('%',:title,'%')
```

MS SQL

```
'%' + :title + '%'
```

Или соберите строку заранее на PHP и передавайте в запрос готовую

```
$params = [
       'title' => "%{$_GET['search']}%" 
    ];
```